# Computed v-for Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Eu tenho um v-for

```
<div  v-for="(m, ind) in arrayMeses" :key="ind" v-if="m" class="mes">
    <table border="1" width="100%">
        <tbody> 
            <tr class="mes_title">
                <td colspan="7" class="mes_title font-14"> 
                    {{ m }} - {{ testeComputed(ind) }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tboddy>
    </table>
```

Eu quero executar um método em cada interação
Quando os dados forem alterados executar também

Eu tentei

```
 computed: {
     testeComputed: function(ind) {
         console.log('m',ind)
         return 'teste' + ind
     },
 },
```

Está retornando um objeto com todos os elementos da página
Eu gostaria de receber o índice ou o nome do mês

Comment: Você tem um loop numa div com uma tabela de uma única linha de uma única coluna? Melhor estudar um pouco mais HTML pra depois ir pro Vue.js

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Tudo bem? É apenas uma parte do código. Está funcionando e montando a tabela como é preciso. Meu problema é na hora de executar o Computed. Eu consigo executar, mas, não consigo passar o parâmetro. Se eu faço um console.log no parâmetro aparece o objeto de todos os componentes da página

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está usando as computed properties de forma errada. Pense no `computed` como uma propriedade somente leitura.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
<div id="exemplo">
  Mensagem ao contrário: {{ mensagem.split('').reverse().join('') }}
</div>
```

Para remover a lógica "bruta" do template, usa-se uma computed property.

> Expressões dentro de templates são muito convenientes, mas são destinadas a operações simples. Colocar muita lógica neles pode fazer com que fiquem inchados e que a sua manutenção fique mais complicada. (["Dados Computados e Observadores", da documentação](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html))

O resultado:

```
<div id="exemplo">
  <p>Mensagem ao contrário: {{ mensagemAoContrario }}</p>
</div>

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    message: 'Olá Vue'
  },
  computed: {
    mensagemAoContrario: function () {
      return mensagem.split('').reverse().join('');
    }
  }
})
```

Se você realmente quer parametrizar isso, pode utilizar um campo no [`data` ou um método mesmo, em `methods`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html).

Comment: Eu resolvi utilizando um method mesmo
Obrigado!